# structure of a sentence verb to be

Tags: grammar

I don't understand the structure of the following sentence and the use of verb to be with the verb.

The owner is entitled to dismiss the manager appointed.

is there three verb here?
is + entitled +dismiss 
and what about appointed?
is it verb also.

Comment: There are **four** verbs: "be", "entitled", "dismiss" and "appointed".

Answer (score 1):

Not really three verbs, but two:

- "*is entitled*" is a conjugated verb in the simple present tense
- "*to dismiss*" is a verb in the infinitive.

Many verbs in English are followed by the infinitive, as in your example:

> "The owner [1]*is entitled* [2]*to dismiss* the manager"

This follows the same structure as:

- He [1]*is coming* [2]*to fix* the television.
- She [1]*is waiting* [2]*to catch* the train.

---

"Appoint" is a verb, but in this case, "appointed" is an *adjective* adding detail to the noun "manager". Someone is *the appointed manager*.

Comment: I don't think "is entitled" is present continuous. And I'd say that "appointed" is a verb (it's an adjective in "appointed manager")

Comment: @BillJ Perhaps it is simple present tense, then. "He is entitled" is the same as "I am entitled", but I thought *entitlement* was ongoing. I've changed it.

Comment: Is (he is entitled) present continous.